Would A Sci-Fi Civilisation Use Magnetic Tape Data Storage Too?
In my story, the primary data storage method for the order of semi-militant and highly augmented archivists that the MC is a part of uses magnetic tape storage for their data. Would a sci-fi civilization using magnetic tape be realistic, or should I explore other possible methods of data storage.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to worldbuilding. It looks like you are asking for our opinion, not giving us a well defined problem to solve. As per our [help], we don't give opinions, we try to solve problems.

A "sci-fi civilization" is a little too undefined for any good answer to be given.  IRL there are situations where there are good reasons to use magnetic tape and situations in which it is a terrible idea, but without a lot more information about the setting we cannot provide an assessment.  What supply chains are available, what threats to the archives are known, what level of maintenance can be relied on, are they in an environment with powerful, oscillating magnetic fields...?

If you tell your readers that the hot new magnetic tape uses advanced technology to store much more data than primitive methods like solid state hard drives, you can have your 70s aesthetic cake and eat it too.

No. Long before they get to become a true space-faring, multiple-star species, IBM will have increased the per-cassette price of tape storage to a number that it many multiples of their entire empire's GDP. They would all have to slave away for decades to purchase just one tape, and it would fail to load the backups. They have no remaining wealth to buy a second one and try again. It might be an extinction-level event for them to even try. If anyone thinks this is a joke, it's only proof of ignorance.

Oh, and I forgot... this is all moot, because they especially can't afford the drive for it. But if they could, they'd probably want to wait for the next model which promises double capacity and should be available sometime in the next 18 months.

If its for archival purposes, than definitely. Check this out.

Yes.
Data centres still use magnetic tape. It is still the cheapest option.
This may seem surprising. Magnetic tape memory degrades. It can have coding so that the flipping of a single bit can be corrected, but periodically, you will need to re-write the archive to correct the bit errors and to strengthen the magnetic records. However, this is something that data centres do anyway. They should periodically check all their records against in-house copies and off-site copies, and generate archive copies for escrow. If they read with an old recorder and write with a new one, they can seamlessly change the format of their records. So, tapes have another ten years of future, and in ten years time they will probably have another ten.
In the further future, we may have tapes that work at the molecular scale. For example, there is a square molecule called a porphyrin. This could be made with ligands at the corners so they self-assemble into a sheet or a tape. The 18-element delocalised pi charge in the centre could be used to store a magnetic state by threading one flux quantum. This would have three states per molecule: flux-up, flux-down, and neutral. You could copy the state non-destructively, or you could do the same read-and-copy cycle that conventional tape does.
Mild predictions:
The tape will be in a cassette. Maybe the read and write heads, and the transport mechanism will be in there too if the tape gets really thin and delicate.
Erasing a tape may disappear. At the molecular scale, individual bits should be almost independent of thermal noise. You can set bits, but it may be hard to reset one bit without disturbing many others. This gets us back to the paper tape days, where no holes is no data, and all holes is an erased character. You might have blocks of data with blanks in between, so you could delete a character and write its replacement in the clear block. This would let you make minor edits to a tape.
This could be part of your plot. You could have two tapes that read the same, but a forensic tape reader could see the edits.

The cheapest option in the current era. No one can tell what technology the future will bring.

Moving a passive medium past a read/write head was there at the start of computing. It has plenty of life in it now, though you probably never see it. It will probably survive a change from metal oxides to quantum dots, then to molecules.

As Richard Kirk said, magnetic tape may seem anachronistic in our NAND-flash era, but it's still the go-to for high-capacity offline data storage. An LTO-9 tape cartridge stores about 15TB (uncompressed) and costs about $90; at that cost, an SSD would only be about 1TB. And, the SSD's data will degrade faster if not actively refreshed by regular reads.
However, despite the longevity of the tech, the anachronism may be hard to overcome for even near-future sci-fi. People hear "tape" and their mind immediately goes to VHS, cassettes etc, which we left behind in the 90s and early 2000s with optical data storage discs (which in turn are also largely considered obsolete). So, I'm leaning toward recommending you handwave something a little more futuristic. If you do go with tape, I'd make it a point to have some exposition as to why; just a sentence or two lampshading the apparent old-school approach to a reader stand-in, and explaining that it's more durable, reliable and cheaper than consumer-grade datacrystals for the same capacity.

As mentioned, magnetic tape is still used on our planet to archive data.  But there is more than that.
For us, the actual tape part is comprised of a thin magnetic layer that comprises magnetic particles suspended in a lubricant, and a polymer binder to keep it all together.
Iron can be used for the magnetic layer, and as the sixth most common element in the universe, it will likely be in a lot of places and available to create this kind of storage.  The polymers as we know them will likely be hydrocarbon based, and in a sci-fi setting should be achievable barring something specifically blocking their creation.  Likewise, any case to put the tape is probably also plastic derived, and the same points apply there too.
Tapes can hold a lot of data, and in a society that continues to pursue this method of archival storage, there are almost certainly improvements that could be made in the ability to store and retain data.
In terms of an "order of semi-militant and highly augmented archivists", it could be that rarer and more exotic elements are used in the militant part of their order, with those materials being directed towards weapons, armours, and shielding, leaving tapes to be the most efficient storage method with the excess materials they have left.
So is it possible, absolutely.  But also you should explore other methods of data storage
Tapes may be good for archiving information, but they are ultimately one giant strip of information.  One would have to move the tape to position it to the correct point to pull needed information off of the tape.  For old archives that are only accessed occasionally, or for data backup and archival purposes, that's fine.  But something accessed more often probably will have a more readily accessible storage method.
Using the same theme, it may be as simple as going to magnetic hard drives, or it could be something different and more science fictiony.  But I would imagine that for common information, they might use faster to access storage.

No, because you should never talk about it.
If you want there to be removeable backup media, then such things exist. You would fetch the backup in its case, you would place the storage unit into or onto the appropriate interface and you would recover the data from it.
Any discussion of what specific form this backup takes should be avoided at all costs. Any overly specific explanation of how such a thing works is universally obsolete within a decade of the story being written. It is simply the removeable backup.

The original Star Wars script - before it became 'Episode IV' had the Death Star plans on 'tapes'.  It's still in the novelisation I have all these years later and look at occasionally, and it's jarring every time I read about the obsolete tech.  I agree, you're better off talking about 'data', 'files' or 'records', not 'tapes'. 'disks' or even 'flash drives'.
